# What is this brown flexible wire with 5 sliding pieces?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

This is definitely one of the strangest LEGO pieces I've ever found.

[image: piece picture]

The wire caps are both stamped LEGO, one would take half (or quarter) a pin and one a small ball.

What is it and where does it come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a flex system cable with several clutch changeover elements strung onto it. You can see it on the back of 8002 Destroyer Droid:

[image: 8002 image]

That's the only set with those parts in brown, so that's certainly where it came from. You can find all of the parts in the [set inventory](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8002-1).

Those cable end elements have never felt quite like LEGO bricks to me, as they are one of the few parts that I feel like I might break when taking them apart.

Comment: The flex cable IS actually quite fragile... also gets brittle with time and stays bent when left in a build for too long...